# Empty vars on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So i have a rails var. It grabs informations from the table and puts it into the page (table)

Heres the controller:

```
giga = @event.gigaurl
@gigaresults = Gigatable.find_by_eventurl(gigantic)
```

Now if the `@gigaresults` is empty. The whole page crashes.

The table it appends to is this.

```
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= @gigaresults.title%>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

If any of these are empty it crashes the page (on heroku) Any ways to avoid this?

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<%= @gigaresults.try(:title) %>
```

will not crash even if @gigaresults is nil.